# Wrong argument count, format string [name] requires 0 but format call supplies 1

Tags: android

I just can't figure out why I'm getting this error, I'm doing the exact same thing in another class, and it works fine (maybe it's an import?)

I want to do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String downloadKey = getString(R.string.pref_download_folder_key); // This will return "pref_download_folder"
String downloadDefault = getString(R.string.pref_download_folder_default);
DownloadFolder = sharedPref.getString(downloadKey, downloadDefault);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Wrong argument count, format string pref_download_folder requires 0 but format call supplies 1

When I change the line to this, everything works fine (note the downloadDefault works, despite being the exact same method):

```
DownloadFolder = sharedPref.getString("pref_download_folder", downloadDefault);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, noticed a few of theme bugs, any way to get it to compile anyway? tried restarting the program with no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an Android Studio bug.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53238

Pressing "run" ran for me fine.
You can also invoke

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

or

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

to build from a command line.

**Edit: this is fixed a while ago, so if you see this in recent versions of Android Studio it's most likely the bug is in your code.**

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Did you find a solution since posting this? Seem to be getting the same thing.

Comment: @RED_ I'm sorry, cannot remember what was the fix (or if there was one).

Comment: This showed up again as a redline error in Android Studio, but does not appear to have any issues at rutime.